# Angularjs: ng-repeat + ng-switch-when != expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

The following code doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
<div ng-switch on="current">
    <div ng-repeat="solution in solutions" ng-switch-when="{{solution.title}}">
        {{solution.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The output of `{{solution.title}}` is literally `{{solution.title}}`. It doesn't get processed by angular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ng-switch-when tag requires a constant, you can't put a variable in it.
You can rework your code as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="solution in solutions">
    <div ng-show="current == solution">
        {{solution.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey remigio. Thanks for your answer but that doesn't cut it. That was actually the first thing I tried. solution.title doesn't get processed by angular either.

Comment: Yeah man, that does work! However I don't see how my version was wrong?!

Comment: *ng-switch-when* couldn't be a variable, it must be a constant

Comment: Maybe try {{ current == solutions }}